# Spliting DataFrame into Multiple Frames by Dates Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I fully understand there are a few versions of this questions out there, but none seem to get at the core of my problem. I have a pandas Dataframe with roughly 72,000 rows from 2015 to now. I am using a calculation that finds the most impactful words for a given set of text (tf_idf). This calculation does  not account for time, so I need to break my main Dataframe down into time-based segments, ideally every 15 and 30 days (or n days really, not week/month), then run the calculation on each time-segmented Dataframe in order to see and plot what words come up more and less over time.

I have been able to build part of this this out semi-manually with the following:

```py
def dateRange():
    start = input("Enter a start date (MM-DD-YYYY) or '30' for last 30 days: ")
    if (start != '30'):
        datetime.strptime(start, '%m-%d-%Y')
        end = input("Enter a end date (MM-DD-YYYY): ")
        datetime.strptime(end, '%m-%d-%Y')
        dataTime = data[(data['STATUSDATE'] > start) & (data['STATUSDATE'] <= end)]
    else:
        dataTime = data[data.STATUSDATE > datetime.now() - pd.to_timedelta('30day')]
    return dataTime

dataTime = dateRange()
dataTime2 = dateRange()

def calcForDateRange(dateRangeFrame):
    ##### LONG FUNCTION####
    return word and number

calcForDateRange(dataTime)
calcForDateRange(dataTime2)
```

This works - however, I have to manually create the 2 dates which is expected as I created this as a test. How can I split the Dataframe by increments and run the calculation for each dataframe?

`dicts` are allegedly the way to do this. I tried:

```py
dict_of_dfs = {}
for n, g in data.groupby(data['STATUSDATE']):
    dict_of_dfs[n] = g

for frame in dict_of_dfs:
    calcForDateRange(frame)
```

The dict result was `2015-01-02: Dataframe` with no frame. How can I break this down into a 100 or so Dataframes to run my function on?

Also, I do not fully understand how to break down `['STATUSDATE']` by number of days specifically?

I would to avoid iterating as much as possible, but I know I probably will have to someehere.

THank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume you have a data frame like this:

```
date = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='31/12/2018', normalize=True)
x = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=365)

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns = ["X"])
df['Date'] = date
df.head()
```

**Output**:

```
    X   Date
0   328 2018-01-01
1   188 2018-01-02
2   709 2018-01-03
3   259 2018-01-04
4   131 2018-01-05
```

So this data frame has 365 rows, one for each day of the year.

Now if you want to group this data into intervals of 20 days and assign each group to a dict, you can do the following

```
df_dict = {}
for k,v in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Date", freq='20D')):
    df_dict[k.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")] = pd.DataFrame(v)
print(df_dict)
```

Comment: This one works, but I am getting another error in my function loop. Not sure why because I ```try, except, dropped``` it before

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this. It creates a dictionary of non empty dataframes keyed on the 
starting date of the period.

```
import datetime as dt

start = '12-31-2017'
interval_days = 30

start_date = pd.Timestamp(start)
end_date = pd.Timestamp(dt.date.today() + dt.timedelta(days=1))
dates = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq=f'{interval_days}d')

sub_dfs = {d1.strftime('%Y%m%d'): df.loc[df.dates.ge(d1) & df.dates.lt(d2)]
           for d1, d2 in zip(dates, dates[1:])}
# Remove empty dataframes.
sub_dfs = {k: v for k, v in sub_dfs.items() if not v.empty}
```